# filtering multiple values based on one matching criteria in a different column in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, alteryx

I have the following set of data in excel that has transactions grouped by Set ID. I want to only view Set IDs that have at least one status1 of "Active" in the group. How do I identify these sets and remove the others that don't have at least one status1 of Active?

[image]

Comment: so is you outcome in place or do you want the outcome in different cells?  If in place do you want this a permanent removal or just filtered?

Comment: Outcome in place and permanent removal please

Comment: Then a Formula will not do this.

Comment: Thanks Scott - will a formula work if outcome is in different cells and just filtered?

Comment: Yes, see the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a possible solution when using Office 365:

```
=LET(data,A1:C11,
     a,INDEX(data,,1),
     c,INDEX(data,,3),
     f,FILTER(a,(c="a")+(ROW(c)=1)),
     m,SIGN(MMULT(--(TRANSPOSE(f)=a),SEQUENCE(ROWS(f),,1,0))),
FILTER(data,m))
```

[image]

(Drop the `+(ROW(c)=1)` if you don't want the header included)